# Reading a property key in Spring Web MVC 3.2.8 with maven

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I have this class in my Spring Web model-view-controller (MVC) framework. The version of the Spring Web model-view-controller (MVC) framework is 3.2.8.

In my `applicationContext.xml` I have this bean definition

```
<bean id="applicationProperties" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertiesFactoryBean">
<property name="locations">
<list><value>classpath:config/application.properties</value></list>
</property> 
</bean>
```

This is the content of the file:

```
templateName = BLE_NORDIC
```

but when I read this property in a JSP I got `????`

```
<fmt:message key="templateName"/>'   >
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add them as message resource bundle

**message.properties**

templateName = BLE_NORDIC

```
<bean id="messageSource" class="org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource"> 
    <property name="basenames"> 
      <list> 
        <value>message</value>  
      </list> 
    </property> 
  </bean>
```